# How to pass multiple parameters in WCF Rest Service: string and Stream in C#

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, stream

I have a WCf rest service which has two input parameters : string and Stream:

```
[OperationContract]      
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "ImportStream/{Separator}", ResponseFormat = 
WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
void ImportStream(string Separator, stream data);
```

My code:

```
public void ImportStream (string Separator, Stream inputpar)
{ //...
}
```

My objectif is to call the service with POSTMAN:
https://localhost:44355/ServiceLias.svc/rest/ImportStream/Comma

and in the body , I write the Stream as Text ,

but I have error from the beginning :

```
For request in operation ImportStream to be a stream the operation must have a single parameter whose type is Stream.
```

How can I fix it ? Or there is any idea to achieve my objectif ? Thanks,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WCF Rest Webservice with stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366489/wcf-rest-webservice-with-stream)

Answer (score 2):

The definition of the function signature doesn’t comply with the rules to enable stream data in WCF. It violates the below definition.

> The parameter that holds the data to be streamed must be the only
>   parameter in the method. For example, if the input message is the one
>   to be streamed, the operation must have exactly one input parameter.
>   Similarly, if the output message is to be streamed, the operation must
>   have either exactly one output parameter or a return value.

Please refer to the official document of how to enable Streaming.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-enable-streaming

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.